# How to make two divs of a total of 100% width fit in the screen

Tags: html, css

here is [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3psysuey/)

I want two divs side by side occupying all the width of the window. I use `display:inline-block` on them so that they behave horizontally.

```
<div id="left" class="horizontal">hello</div>
<div id="right" class="horizontal">world</div>
```

The problem is that when I set their width to equal 100% (left at 20% and right at 80%) they take larger than the screen, and the div on the right gets pushed under the other one.

I get around this by setting the width smaller than 100% (19% and 79%) but this has some minor problems later on, sometimes putting unwanted spaces where I do not want it.

**What am I missing to make it that my divs get along horizontally while using 100% of the screen?**

I have seen the tricks listed [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/), as well as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078297/576767)... and most of them are so ugly I still prefer using a less than 100% width.

```
* {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    border-spacing:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
}
#left {
    background-color: red;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
}
#right {
    background-color: green;
    width:80%;
    height:100%;
}
.horizontal {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would not use `inline-block`, but `block` instead. Add `position: relative` and `float: left` to `.horizontal` and it works...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: What Billy said is an alternative way doing it, it's not an answer to your question, it didn't explain why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to use `inline-block` I would recommend to use `block` instead. `block` is the default value for the `display` of a `div`, so you do not have to explicitly set it. Just set the `float` to `left` and you won't have to "fight the space between inline block elements".

Example:

```
.horizontal {
  float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It has to do with display: inline-block which adds a small number of pixels between items.  I've had this problem too.

From [CSS-Tricks] (https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/)

Comment: None of the solutions are nice.  As i recall I ended up not using inline-block for divs.  You can display them as blocks, use absolute positioning or use some sort of front-end grid system (bootstrap, foundation, bourbon/neat)

Comment: I really don't see why the bloat of a front-end grid is a better a solution.

Comment: I've used bootstrap a bit and some bourbon/neat.  I'm not a huge fan of them especially bootstrap because it puts style back into the markup, but they are an option for handling this sort of thing and are quite popular.